# How do I start of creation a web application fragment?

Tags: maven, jsf, web-fragment

I have been working on a Maven project when I created a screen to display some data. I have finished the required web pages however I was asked to put the webpages into an application fragment. I have completed inside a web application but I am confused "How can I can start web app fragment with maven and JSF?" Thanks.

Comment: Try to create one without maven first

Answer (score 0):

When you use, for example, NetBeans, you can choose the example of webapp. Also, when you create a project you will have a basic stuff of files, for example: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/
, https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/webapp.html and http://howtodoinjava.com/maven/how-to-create-a-eclipse-web-application-using-maven/

Comment: i have already created the webapp no problem, however i was asked to now make my webapp into a web application fragment. after some research i found out i need a web-fragment.xml somewhere however i dont know to convert my project into a fragment.

Comment: So, I understood your question now. Here is one of the examples: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwebfragproj.html